# What is the shortest total path between pairs of points?

Tags: shortest-path, traveling-salesman

I have 2n random points on a plane. Join pairs of points to make paths. Pair the points such that the summed path length is a minimum. In the picture below, we are trying to minimise the total length of all red-line segments. Points cannot be reused.

Obviously there's the naive brute-force solution, but I wonder if there's a better way. I thought about picking the smallest path then eliminating and picking the next smallest path but then that doesn't guarantee the shortest overall path.

Any pointers welcome.
[image]

Comment: Does the path need to be connected? Can a point belong to more than one pair?

Comment: I think I've clarified in an edit - and I've added a diagram of what I mean as well.

Comment: This is equivalent to finding closest pair of points and adding the distance between all those pairs. You can always use Divide and Conquer to find the closest pair of points and apply the same algorithm 2n/2 times, eliminating one such pair each time. This could be done in O((n^2)lgn) times, not tightly bounded (upper bound). So, I think we can bring that down to O(n *((lgn)^2)).

Comment: It is absolutely not equivalent. Consider four points on a line at 0, 5, 6, 10. With your method the total length would be (6 - 5) + (10 - 0) = 11. But that is not the solution. The solution is ((5 - 0) + (10 - 6)) = 9.

Answer (score 4):

This appears to be a [maximum matching](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_weight_matching) problem.  Well, minimum matching, but you should be able to make the necessary adaptations.

Answer (score 0):

This is a modification of a maximum matching problem, as answered by DW. Modifying Hopcroft-Karp for this use is a undergrad uni level assignment (one I had to do myself at that level).